# nginx is still using the default directory instead of what i specified

Tags: php, nginx

The following is my nginx.conf file, i am not using the sites-available directory and just wanted to use the .conf file so that i can see everything. I have also restarted nginx and when i type in the ip address i still see the default directory coming up and as for the domain it does nothing. Here is my .conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 1;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    #error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    ######### VIRTUAL HOSTS ############
    # default
    server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        root /var/www/vhosts/some-site-ihave;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        access_log /var/www/logs/some-site-ihave/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/logs/some-site-ihave/error.log;

        #load php via php5-fpm
        location \
        {
            proxy_pass http://some-site-ihave.com;
        }
    }

    #some-site-ihave.com
    server
    {
        listen 80;
        server_name some-site-ihave.com;
        root /var/www/vhosts/some-site-ihave;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        access_log /var/www/logs/some-site-ihave/access.log;
        error_log /var/www/logs/some-site-ihave/error.log;

        #load php via php5-fpm
        location ~ \.php$
        {
            try_files $uri = 404;
            fastcgi_pass unix: /var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: is the default server configured inside `sites-enabled` ? or `conf.d` ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already seem to want to make that server your default, then remove the `server_name _;` server block and replace `listen 80;` in your second server with `listen 80 default_server;`, reload nginx and you're done